# Parse Error on input 'appendString' Haskell

Tags: haskell

Hey guys so this is a strange little error I'm getting and I'm not understand why it's giving it to me.

It says Parse Error in input 'appendString' yet I see nothing wrong with it...

I call it from an if,then else statement as follows:

```
createShow currentIndex (Grid {delta = d, middle = (x,y), points = g}) dir counter = 
if currentIndex ==0 || dir == 2
    then (appendString d (x,y) g currentIndex) ++ (createShow currentIndex+1 (Grid {delta = d, middle = (x,y), points = g}) 2 (counter+1))
else if counter == (2*d+1)
    then (appendString d (x,y) g currentIndex) ++ (appendX x)
else if dir == 1
    then (appendString d (x,y) g currentIndex) ++ (createShow currentIndex-1 (Grid {delta = d, middle = (x,y), points = g}) 1 (counter+1))
```

where createShow returns a string and so does appendString

appendString gives the error in the constructor:

```
 appendString d (x,y) g currentIndex = 
(if currentIndex == y 
    then "y "
 else 
    "  " ) ++ (show currentIndex) ++(rowFunction g x d 0 (x+d) 1)++ "\n"
```

do you see where I could have gone wrong with it?

Edit: Added entire area

Comment: Please paste the full section of code

Comment: Though it's unrelated to the error you're asking about, you need parentheses around `currentIndex-1`.

Comment: Looks like an indentation issue. Also, you should use guards instead of nested `if`.

Comment: indentation issue? Do you see where?

Comment: There is a space before `appendString`. The opening `(if` needs to be nested deeper than `appendString`, not outdented from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell `if`'s are not like other `if`'s in say Java or python. The biggest difference is that they are *expressions* unlike java or python where they are statements.

They are much closer to the `condition ? res1 : res2` from C.

The correct way to write nested if's is like this:

```
if condition
  then foo
  else if condition2
         then bar
         else ...
```

You'll notice that this is horribly ugly.

That's why haskell has guards:

```
foo args | condition = foo
         | condition2= bar
         | otherwise = meh
```

Here we declare a function `foo` and if `condition` is true then we execute `foo` otherwise we proceed to `condition2` and `otherwise` is always true. For you

```
createShow currentIndex (Grid {delta = d, middle = (x,y), points = g}) dir counter
  | currentIndex == 0 || dir == 2 = appendString d ....
  | counter == (2 * d + 1)        = appendString d ....
  | dir == 1                      = appendString d ....
```

which looks much more readable.

Comment: Thanks! That completely worked and helped me understand why I was indenting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactoring::

```
createShow currentIndex grid@(Grid {delta = d, middle = (x,y), points = g}) dir counter =
    prefix ++ show currentIndex ++ row ++ "\n" ++ nextLine
  where
    prefix = if currentIndex == y then "y " else "  "
    row = rowFunction g x d 0 (x+d) 1

    nextLine | currentIndex == 0 || dir == 2 = createShow (currentIndex+1) grid 2 (counter+1)
    nextLine | counter == (2*d+1)            = appendX x
    nextLine | dir == 1                      = createShow (currentIndex-1) grid 1 (counter+1)

    appendX x = ...
```

Things to notice:

- Using a `where` clause often lets you avoid repeating parameters
- The common call to `appendString` has been factored out, and moved to the top, and then in-lined, since it is only called once.
- Use of guards in `nextLine` to handle a cascaded `if` more clearly.
- The guards and form of `nextLine` make it clear it isn't a *total* function. What happens when it falls off the end?
- The use of `grid@` to name a pattern. This way you don't need to "reconstruct" the `Grid` value when making the recursive calls.

One can go further. Noticing that `Grid {...}` and `dir` never change throughout the function suggests factoring those out:

```
createShow currentIndex (Grid {delta = d, middle = (x,y), points = g}) dir counter =
    line currentIndex counter
  where
    line currentIndex counter =
        prefix ++ show currentIndex ++ row ++ "\n" ++ nextLine currentIndex counter

    prefix = if currentIndex == y then "y " else "  "
    row = rowFunction g x d 0 (x+d) 1

    nextLine currentIndex counter
        | currentIndex == 0 || dir == 2 = line (currentIndex+1) (counter+1)
        | counter == (2*d+1)            = appendX x
        | dir == 1                      = line (currentIndex-1) (counter+1)

    appendX x = ...
```

Here, `line` plays the part of "carrying" around the only values that differ as the function recurses. It would be a common idiom to place those arguments at the end of what `createShow` takes, and thus even factor them out:

```
createShow :: Grid -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String
createShow (Grid {delta = d, middle = (x,y), points = g}) dir = line
  where
    line currentIndex counter =
        prefix ++ show currentIndex ++ row ++ "\n" ++ nextLine currentIndex counter

    prefix = if currentIndex == y then "y " else "  "
    row = rowFunction g x d 0 (x+d) 1

    nextLine currentIndex counter
        | currentIndex == 0 || dir == 2 = line (currentIndex+1) (counter+1)
        | counter == (2*d+1)            = appendX x
        | dir == 1                      = line (currentIndex-1) (counter+1)

    appendX x = ...
```